# Displaying stack view not from top

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uistackview

Struggling on this question second day. I am facing problem with displaying stack view into scroll view. My main problem is that when I open detail view with content it starts to display all information approximately from the middle of all content
Here is an image:
[Here is an image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGYDc.jpg)

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private let scrollStackViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 10
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
        view.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        return view
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .label
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollStackViewContainer)
        scrollStackViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(gifImageView)
        scrollStackViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(idLabel)
        scrollStackViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        scrollStackViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(publishDateLabel)
        scrollStackViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(spacerView)
        scrollStackViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(addToFavoriteButton)
        applyConstraints()
    }
    private func applyConstraints() {
        let scrollViewConstraits = [
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ]
        let scrollStackViewContainerConstraints = [
            scrollStackViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            scrollStackViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            scrollStackViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            scrollStackViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            scrollStackViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(scrollViewConstraits)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(scrollStackViewContainerConstraints)
    }
}
```

What should I do to display all UI element initially from the top of scroll view.
[Like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJsGJ.jpg)

Comment: I think the constraints are quite correct. How did you set `gifImageView height`?

Comment: *"starts to display all information approximately from the middle of all content"* -- What does that mean? The image you posted doesn't tell us anything... how is it different from what you are expecting?

Comment: On the first image there is space between top navigation bar and image. I want to avoid this space between. Displaying this detail view without this space like in the second image

Comment: @olehart - this is what I get, using your code almost as-is. The only changes I made: gave the (red) `spacerView` a height constraint of 20, gave the labels background colors so we can see them, and set the scrollView background color to system yellow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1xqm.png ... does your dog image maybe have a large white or transparent space at the top?